# Energy difference in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, energy

Why exactly are absolute energies important in General Relativity, unlike for example EM where only energy differences matter?

Answer (score 3):

Einstein's equation relates the curvature of space to the [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), and the dominant component of the stress-energy tensor is usually the energy density $T_{00}$. This is the amount of energy per unit volume, and it's an absolute quantity not a difference.